# How do I make raw peanut butter creamy?

Tags: butter, raw, peanuts

I bought fresh ground peanut butter, and it's great and all, and I really like it for peanut sauces, but I really just want a peanut butter and jelly sandwich and this stuff just isn't right for that.

- What additives should I mix in to get a more classic PB&J peanut butter from fresh ground, raw peanut butter?
- I am sure I will need to adjust on the fly, but what kind of oil should I add? Sugar? Salt?
- What equipment should I use to mix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've pretty much answered your own question. Put the PB in a blender, drizzle in a little peanut oil, blitz and season to taste with salt and a little sugar if you want it. I'd add them all slowly: you can always add, you can't take away.

Answer (score 0):

Any neutral oil (canola, sunflower, etc.) should work just fine, and you won't need much. I like to do this in my food processor right after I grind the peanuts, but you can just throw the raw peanut butter in there.